# 1, 2, 3, soleil?

Tags: riddle, cipher, wordplay

## What happened to me ?

Don't you know what happened to me ? Everybody knows !

Maybe this epic poetry will refresh your memories...

> I’m looking over the riddle 
>       It’s no puzzle to me
>       For I am 
>       Guiding this story 
>       Qhu mbmfc ron’li udxvxl 
>       Wgdoiga Zayxnxli’k ersmyvq 
>       Tnt riy fwxd mbi zsvk fuwlwk 
>       Th wsflbnny aala mx 
>   
>       Rmme qsohmxgd vjxxve zxf 
>       Rsg lpdt kid tcsdoc 
>       Dhp xfbx uej st jsb nz yoi 
>       Yxlpct cse adu ni 
>   
>       Bfna, is bshd jjsehhip bpa klu 
>       xhl xxo utqi lht frxtk 
>       Z edse ue ft i boovyod ujbk pdng iby 
>       kmg T osjo wn qjfsl ve edf tqv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**FINAL SOLUTION**

**Note**

> I have found the key's straight through analysis and haven't discovered any clues(if any)

Qhu mbmfc ron’li udxvxl
Wgdoiga Zayxnxli’k ersmyvq
Tnt riy fwxd mbi zsvk fuwlwk
Th wsflbnny aala mx

**Solving the above**

> Doing some analysis with the cipher, it seems the key is **STATUES** which has another name Soleil in the [Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statues_(game)). Applying the key gives -
>
>  You think you’re clever
>  Solving Vigenere’s mystery
>  But you need the hack master
>  To continue with me

**Solving the rest**

> As @SP3000 pointed out, the encryption is multi-layered. Hence, the rest of the text after applying **STATUES** is - 
>
>  Xium xsvnifok vqdtdm gxm
>  Xoo twda qel bjskuy
>  Lpw xmht cmq sa poj vg yvo
>  Uftwca iom iku uo
>
>  Xnvh, iz hopl qjzkdpqw bwg gtc
>  ehs dtw caqp rdb nyxaq
>  V mlze bk bb q iovbuwl bjiq llvn iie
>  guo A ozpk ev xjmyh dm ldm zmd

**Now,**

> Applying key as KASISKI(@SP3000 referred [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kasiski_examination))we get -
>
>  Nice findings little one
>  Now lets get tricky
>  The next key is for no one
>  Unless you ask me
>
>  Xvnp, yr xoxd yzradxie row gbu
>  mxk tte uigh hdj fgnsg
>  V udhu ta bj i qenrued jzag ltnv yau
>  gcg I erfk mn fzeoh le tte pml

**Final Part**

> @Will found the right key as **FINALDRAMA** which gives
>
>  Snap, no gold treasure for you
>  but the path was funny
>  I used to be a decoder just like you
>  but I took an arrow in the key

**Final note to the author**

> If this is the intended solution, you might as well either wait for someone to find the clues or provide an explanation for the clues to get the keys (if there are any). If not, were the keys supposed to be a guess work?

Comment: The second one has the key `eekalkb` but I've no clue why.

Comment: Will I am updating it :D Got it a minute back. And yes, even I do not have any clues :p

Comment: Nice !
It's true that 'eekalkb' cracks the second paragraph, however, it wasn't the key I used... How is it possible ?

I'll consider myself as defeated if you solve it all using only analysis, but I'm really curious to see if you can follow the path ;)

Comment: The decryption is nested, so you decrypt all of paragraphs 2-4 to get one new plaintext paragraph and two new ciphertexts. The actual second key is KASISKI.

Comment: @Sp3000 How does KASISKI work?

Comment: @LilianDelaveau Out of curiosity, are there any clues which provide a way to find the keys? It seems I am now stuck at the last para as the key length looks to be a bigger one (probably 10 or 11 characters long)

Comment: So if you decrypt paragraphs 2-4 using the first key, the new paragraphs 3-4 starts with "Xium...". Using [KASISKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kasiski_examination) (the "hack master" for polyalphabetic ciphers is the intent, I'm guessing) gives what you have in your post.

Comment: Note that our previous "key" works because `uesstat` enciphered using key `kasiski` is `eekalkb`

Comment: @Sp3000 Ah, that sounds plausible. Will, yes, just checked that. But, it's quite arbitrary and is not easily solvable manually. I do not find any clues for any of those keys yet :-/

Comment: And... `finaldrama`

Comment: @Will Excellent! :p

Comment: The others I can tangentially understand how the key was intended to be clued by hindsight, but I am stumped as to how the messages relate for that last one

Comment: @Sp3000 True. If you want to add a post explaining the clues, you may go ahead and do it. Personally, I do not see any easily identifiable clues to crack the keys.

Comment: It's really all hindsight - STATUES as you've noted ties in with the title (According to the Statues article you've linked, in France it's apparently "un, deux trois, soleil" <-> 1, 2, 3 soleil), and for the second one you use the Vigenere "hack master" (KASISKI) as the key to continue. Not going to post a separate answer though.

Comment: Hey there ! Congrats for solving it all. There were clues and a way to solve it without analysis. But of course when you finally get the keys looking for it must be boring ;) I'll write the clues and all later today :) Sp3000 is on the right track. Please note there would have been hints every day or so ;)